# prototype in typescript:Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '_BaseOption' has no index signature

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want use prototype in typescript.

```
export class base{
    constructor() {
        base.prototype["g"] = new option({});
    }
}
```

Line 3  shows this:[ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'base' has no index signature.

Help!

Comment: The code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the index signature to your `base` class:

```
export class base{
    [prop: string]: option
    constructor() {
        base.prototype["g"] = new option({});
    }
}
```

But doing so means that any property you access via index signature on `base` instance will also be typed as `option`. Example:

```
let doesNotExist = new base()["doesNotExist"]; // Will compile fine without throwing error.
```

If you are going to add only a limited set of properties to the prototype you can just add those properties alone:

```
export class base{
    g: option
    constructor() {
        base.prototype["g"] = new option({});
    }
}

let g = new base()["g"] // OK
let doesNotExist = new base()["doesNotExist"] // Error
```